# A nightly task to backup a database to MS Access

Tags: sql-server, database, windows, ms-access, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to create a nightly task which will download my SQL Server database into MSAccess 2010 as a "nightly snapshot" and so far, I have it working.

I created a blank database with macro's inside of it which can perform the import, then exit gracefully. It works great under my username:

```
@echo off
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c%%a%%b)
set dest=c:\temp\%mydate%-RAVEN.accdb
xcopy BLANK_RAVEN_WITH_MACROS.accdb %dest%* /Y
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE" %dest% /X IMPORT_RAVEN
```

However, when I run the task as the SYSTEM user (note -- I'm not supposed to run tasks as my own username) nothing happens.

For the record, the SYSTEM user does have access to my other database and the SYSTEM account can copy the MS Access Blank file to the Destination. However nothing happens with Access. I simply see MSAccess running in the background indefinitely as SYSTEM. It never exits

How can I run MSAccess and run a macro through the SYSTEM user account?

Comment: Why not back up using bcp instead?  Is Access doing some additional processing, and if so, could that not be put directly on the database?

Comment: Bcp? Can his show an example of this?

Comment: This is a Sybase example, but the parameters should be very similar.  This would back up a table to a file:  `bcp sales.dbo.order_header out c:/cdh/temp.dat -n -S myserver -U scott -P tiger`.  If you ever needed to restore it, it would be `bcp <table> in` instead of `out`.  The `-n` means "native" meaning the resulting file will be unreadable, but it eliminates any delimitation error, handles any datatype and the file size is smaller than the `-c` readable output

Comment: By the way, it's also very fast, both the backup and recovery.

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft Access application (MSACCESS.EXE) is designed to be run by "real" users so it probably makes some assumptions about the environment in which it is executing. One of those assumptions could likely be that the account under which it is running has the standard locations where program settings can be stored and retrieved, e.g., %USERPROFILE% in the filesystem and HKEY_CURRENT_USER in the registry. If those locations are unavailable when running under an account like SYSTEM then MSACCESS.EXE might get hung up.

If possible, create an account with the minimum necessary permissions and run your Scheduled Task under that account.

Comment: That won't be possible in my IT environment. Is there a way to run the macro via ODBC or some database-like calls?

Comment: Macro? No. To run the macro you'd need an instance of Access, either by directly running MSACCESS.EXE (as you are doing) or via COM automation with an `Access.Application` object. You could try the COM automation approach to see if it works any better, but I wouldn't be surprised if the same assumptions apply.

Comment: If not a Macro, what about VBA code within Access? Could that be executed on the database through ODBC?

Comment: No. VBA code in the Access database would also require resources from an Access instance. (That's why custom VBA functions can't be used in queries that are run from outside of Access itself.)

Comment: Hmm I wonder if it would be worth contacting Microsoft Support over this. I wonder if I could link them to this stackoverflow page?

Comment: They may just point you [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/230575) where it says "**Note** Using the system account does not work correctly." and then suggest that you use SSIS to push the data from SQL Server to Access.